# How to share a state/data between two child component without updating parent component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

[Here I have A as parent component and B & C are its child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvju8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvju8.jpg)

can anybody help me to understand how can I send a data from B to C and vice versa without updating A

Comment: use Context or Redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to not do is 'props drilling'. The solution for that is to use a global state. But this would require a 'setup' on A parent component. not necessarily in the 'A' component but it definitely needs to be a parent component of the children. React has a built in API for it and it's called [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). If you wanna use a third-party library there's other popular solutions like [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) etc.

If you don't have to share state, just the data, there are ways to do it. You can have a global Variable declared from a child component (Not recommended) Or you can set data on the [Localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser and consume from different components. You don't need to update the parent for these solutions.